# Parameterized OPENJSON in SQL Server query using Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, json, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-core

```
context.Set<BlogKeyValuePair>()
   .FromSql("SELECT [key], value FROM OPENJSON((SELECT JsonData FROM dbo.Blogs WHERE BlogId=1), '$.@path')", 
        new SqlParameter("@path", "path.to.data"));
```

On first sighting this should work correctly and `@path` should be replace by `path.to.data` but it doesn't, an SqlException is thrown with the following error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect syntax near '@path'.

Seems like SQL server does not replace the parameter because it is a parameter inside the `OPENJSON` function.

Looking for secure workarounds.

Comment: Share the full stack trace!

Answer (score 3):

SQL does not recognize the variable because you put it inside a string:

```
-- Wrong:
OPENJSON((SELECT JsonData FROM dbo.Blogs WHERE BlogId = 1), '$.@path')

-- Correct:
OPENJSON((SELECT JsonData FROM dbo.Blogs WHERE BlogId = 1), '$.' + @path)
```

Code:

```
context
    .Set<BlogKeyValuePair>()
    .FromSql(@"
        SELECT [key], value
        FROM OPENJSON((SELECT JsonData FROM dbo.Blogs WHERE BlogId = 1), '$.' + @path)",
        new SqlParameter("@path", "path.to.data"));
```

Comment: This does not work for me. Have you checked it yourself? Perhaps I am missing something. I am getting "Incorrect syntax near '+'."

Comment: Try concatenate two strings into OPENJSON's path parameter inside SSMS or any other tool you use to manage your DB.

Comment: @J.Doe This should work fine and David Browne's SQL worked for me too. Not a clue why it gives you syntax errors. Have you tried it inside SMSS? Seems like not the code but something else is broken. Have you tried it using a plain string for the path without a parameter? Have you tried putting the full path in the parameter, incl. the `$.`?

Comment: Yes I have tried inside SMSS. Yes I have tried using a plain string for the path without a parameter and it does work. And yes for the `$.` inside my parameter

Comment: @J.Doe If tried David Browne's SQL using the .NET functionality under System.Data.SqlClient and it worked fine too, even using the parameter. I wonder if EF Core performs some internal syntax checks? I don't believe that though.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me in SSMS, so @marsze's answer should work.

```
declare @path nvarchar(2000) = 'ArrayValue';

DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(4000) = N'{  
   "StringValue":"John",  
   "IntValue":45,  
   "TrueValue":true,  
   "FalseValue":false,  
   "NullValue":null,  
   "ArrayValue":["a","r","r","a","y"],  
   "ObjectValue":{"obj":"ect"}  
}'

SELECT *
FROM OPENJSON(@json, '$.' + @path)
```

Comment: I'm copying exactly that and I'm still getting "Incorrect syntax near '+'."
Any idea why?

Comment: @J.Doe If you changed your code, then add your new code in your question!